# Is there a Fiddler plugin for binary XML?

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, binary, fiddler

Fiddler has [many useful extensions](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/extensions.asp).  However, I can't find one that understands WCF's binary-encoded SOAP envelopes.  (Content-Type: application/soap+msbin1)

Suggestions for comparable (non-Fiddler) tools are welcome too.

Comment: Is turning on WCF message tracing not an option?

Comment: An option, but not optimal.  1) Not real time.  2) To my knowledge doesn't capture raw headers, ntlm auth, etc.  3) Can't toggle settings when client is Silverlight, at least not easily.  4) Missing cool features like Replay.

Comment: 1) How is it not real-time? 2) None of those headers are in the binary XML - they're in the transport protocol. 3) Toggling at the server side is not adequate? 4) Conceded.

Comment: 1) From my scan of MSDN [admittedly no direct experience], SvcTraceViewer.exe reads files from disk.  I didn't see mention of an interactive mode that can attach & read on the fly a la DebugView.  2) Right.  When a problem is reported I don't know a priori what layer to debug.  Would be nice to have just 1 tool.  3) See #2.  At best I'm opening another tool/environment again; at worst, the issue may be preventing the client from reaching the intended endpoint at all.

Comment: Is there a protocol document for the binary-encoded SOAP protocol?  Writing new inspectors for Fiddler is super-duper easy (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/inspectors.asp), and it seems likely that .NET already includes a library for parsing WCF messages.

Comment: Thanks for your great feedback on the extensibility model, Richard!  When your Inspector is complete, I'd be happy to advertise it on the Fiddler site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After lots of work on ancillary stuff that doesn't really matter (eg decided to roll my own quick-n-dirty recursive descent XML parser), I've just committed the first checkin where the plugin actually does its job in a usable fashion.  Still extremely rough around the edges, with many features not implemented, but if you want to see binary WCF in Fiddler now's your chance!

Source code only for now: http://tfstoys.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/26191?projectName=tfstoys#BinaryXMLInspector

I'll post binaries on CodePlex when it's polished enough for general consumption.  Probably won't remember to update this "answer" though.  If you're reading this months/years from now, be sure to click over to the Downloads page -- or at minimum, grab the latest source instead of this changeset.

Comment: Link is dead at this point.

Answer (score 5):

I've also created a rough and ready inspector for WCF Binary messages. You can find mine (including binaries) at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfbinaryinspector

It differs from Richard's in that I use WCF's own decoder, rather than rolling my own. Source code for that is [on my blog](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/11/fiddler-plug-in-for-inspecting-wcf.html).

Comment: Link is dead at this point.  I've added a new answer with a different plugin mentioned in the blog comments.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a Burp plug-in for editing Binary XML data based on Richard Bergs decoder.  You can find the plug-in and a Blog post explaining how it works here: http://www.gdssecurity.com/l/b/2009/11/19/wcf-binary-soap-plug-in-for-burp/

Comment: It would be nice if more than a link were included in this answer. Just providing a link as an answer is discouraged. Perhaps including some of the high level details from the post in this answer would go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one from the Silverlight 4 team: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2010/05/10/fiddler-inspector-for-wcf-silverlight-polling-duplex-and-wcf-ria.aspx

Direct download link (Click "Fiddler Extension for Binary Message Encoding") http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightws/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4059

Comment: Links are dead at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Many years later the other answers for Fiddler are dead links.  This one still is still available and working:
https://github.com/waf/WCF-Binary-Message-Inspector